# FPGA based theremin , is possible?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, verilog, theremin

I remember a while ago , i saw some Digital based Theremins circuits from glasgow university...

http://www.theremin.info/-/viewpub/tid/10/pid/65

would it be possible to make a theremin by using an FPGA ?

Comment: FPGAs are _strictly_ digital. That means, you either convert those analog parts to digital domain, or build an analog stuff around it.

Comment: @Dzarda: Not quite true. http://www.microsemi.com/products/fpga-soc/fpga/fusion

Comment: @JerryCoffin Interesting. One might argue though, that those aren't _Gate Arrays_ per se. :)

Comment: @Dzarda: Fair enough--and technically there's no real question that you're right. Regardless of the terminology, however, they're interesting parts that seem worth knowing about.

Comment: @Dzarda: As a side note: It is possible to write some evolutionary algorithm that creates an fpga layout that does behave like an analogue one... this is by exploiting manufacturing tolerances. Unfortunately the programming is different per chip (and ambient temperature)

Comment: @PlasmaHH WOW ...

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, although it's really not a good fit for an FPGA project and the FPGA is mostly useless.

Fundamentally a Theremin is a capacitative sensor device like a smartphone's touchscreen or proximity sensor, but tuned to very high sensitivity. See [this Arduino theremin](http://interface.khm.de/index.php/lab/experiments/theremin-as-a-capacitive-sensing-device/), which would be a good basis to adapt from. There may be capsense libraries or IP cores for your FPGA which would make is easier.